# Can't trigger click event in loaded modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

So, I render partial view as bs modal, inside of it I have file input , which i want to be opened immediately as modal is shown. I have tried many Many MANY ways to make it work but it keeps resisting :) Maybe someone has clue whats the problem.

Here is my View JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).off('shown.bs.modal', '#js-edit-avatar-modal');
    $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#js-edit-avatar-modal',
        function() {
            console.log($('#browse-btn'));
            $('#browse-btn').click();
        });
});
```

Input in modal:

```
<label id="browse-btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                @ApplicationStrings.BrowseText
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" onchange="readUrl(this);" style="display: none" />
            </label>
```

This is console:

[image: Console screenshot]

First one was triggered with

> console.log($('#browse-btn'));

Other two i typed manually, second shows that it returns the same object, and third opens Input dialog properly.

I have tried: Removing display:none, using `$('#browse-btn').trigger('click');` changing event to show.bs.modal, setting 2 sec delay after modal is shown then triggering click event, tried to trigger another button with just logging functionality, still did not work.
 Maybe there are some security restrictions to automatically call click event on hidden buttons? But when I made it visible it still did not work, and typing exact same

> $('#browse-btn').click();

in console always works.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: I've got same issue with `change` events

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with below code and let me know if works or not.

```
$('#browse-btn').trigger("click");
```

Comment: i forgot to add, i did try this as well :/ its not about that line, when typed in console both  `$('#browse-btn').trigger("click")` and `$('#browse-btn').click();` work.